# How to call performSegueWithIdentifier from xib?

Tags: ios, swift, view, segue, xib

I have viewController with segue to secondViewController named "toSecond".
In viewController i load customView.xib

```
let myCustomView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("customView", owner: self, options: nil)[0]
```

in this customView i have button with action:

```
viewController().goToSecond()
```

in viewController i have function with this code

```
func goToSecond() {
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toSecond", sender: self)
}
```

but when i pressed button in customView i become a error:

> viewController has no segue with identifier 'toSecond'

when i call this function directly from viewController all work great!

So, how can i call performSegueWithIdentifier from my customView?

customView source code:

```
import UIKit

class customView: UIView {

@IBAction func ToSecondButton(sender: AnyObject) {
viewController().goToSecond() }

}
```

viewController source code:

```
import UIKit

class viewController: UIViewController {

...
let myCustomView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("customView", owner: self, options: nil)[0]
self.view.addSubview(myCustomView)
func goToSecond() {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toSecond", sender: self)
    }
...

}
```

Comment: If the File's Owner for the custom view is the view controller, I don't understand how this code:

`viewController().goToSecond()`

is contained inside your custom view.  Could you provide more of the source code for your custom view? How are you creating a reference to the view controller inside the custom view?

Comment: i present customView in presenting viewController... My segue between viewController and secondViewController... i can call func goToSecond() from viewController directly but can't from customView! if in function goToSecond write something like print("Click!") i see this click in log!

Comment: In the future, I'd encourage you to stick to [Cocoa naming conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-1002242-BBCIJGDB), where all class names start with uppercase letters. This was unnecessarily confusing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `UIView` subclass is calling `viewController().goToSecond()`. That's not doing what you think it is. The `viewController()` isn't referencing the view controller that loaded your custom view. It's instantiating a second, orphaned instance of that class (not connected to any storyboard) and therefore cannot find the segue.

If you're really going to have this custom `UIView` subclass initiate a segue, you need to pass a reference to your original view controller to the custom view. So add a property to the custom view subclass that can hold the reference to its view controller, and when the view controller instantiates this custom view, it has to set that property.

---

For example:

```
import UIKit

protocol CustomViewDelegate: class {         // make this class protocol so you can create `weak` reference
    func goToNextScene()
}

class CustomView: UIView {

    weak var delegate: CustomViewDelegate?   // make this `weak` to avoid strong reference cycle b/w view controller and its views

    @IBAction func toSecondButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.goToNextScene() 
    }

}
```

And then

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CustomViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myCustomView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("customView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! CustomView
        myCustomView.delegate = self

        // ... do whatever else you want with this custom view, adding it to your view hierarchy
    }


    func goToNextScene() {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("toSecond", sender: self)
    }

    ...

}
```